# How to change theme and color in Android app

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm making a Notes app and want to create many themes for users to choose from

However, I don't know how to edit the colors.xml file to use it specifically for each theme

This is the colors.xml file located in values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<color name="black">#FF000000</color>
<color name="color_icon_menu">#67686C</color>
<color name="color_icon_setting">#67686C</color>
<color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
<color name="bg_main">#f7f7f7</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#3559FA</color>
<color name="color_text_default">#22252e</color>
<color name="color_text_default_p">#A6000000</color>

<color name="color_text_default_2">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="color_F8F6F4">#F8F6F4</color>
<color name="color_item">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="bg_bottom_navigation_2">#fefefe</color>
<color name="bg_view">#33000000</color>
<color name="bnv_selected_3">#ffbb00</color>
<color name="color_2">#4DC7D3</color>
<color name="color_3">#01FF73</color>
<color name="color_4">#4AB311</color>
<color name="color_5">#CD9913</color>
<color name="color_6">#EA39FD</color>
<color name="color_7">#4837DF</color>
<color name="color_8">#D0A9E8</color>
<color name="color_9">#0c84ff</color>
<color name="color_text_default_80">#CC22252E</color>
<color name="color_text_default_60">#9922252E</color>
<color name="color_text_default_40">#6622252E</color>
<color name="color_text_default_20">#3322252E</color>
<color name="color_text_hint">#9F9797</color>
<color name="color_reason">#929395</color>
<color name="color_bg_popup">#14000000</color>

<color name="color_item_selected">#f4f7ff</color>
<color name="color_4cd964">#4CD964</color>
<color name="color_e3e3e3">#E3E3E3</color>
<color name="color_highlight">#FFD740</color>
<color name="color_on_highlight">#000000</color>
<color name="color_gray">#668A989E</color>
<color name="color_red">#F44336</color>
<color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="color_keyboard">#f7f7f7</color>

<color name="pinFieldLibraryAccent">#FF4081</color>
<color name="inactivePinFieldColor">#808080</color>
<color name="pinFieldLibraryTransparent">#00000000</color>
<color name="color_bg_navigation">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_1_start">#6190E8</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_1_end">#A7BFE8</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_2_start">#16222A</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_2_end">#3A6073</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_3_start">#3CA55C</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_3_end">#B5AC49</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_4_start">#B79891</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_4_end">#94716B</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_5_start">#9796f0</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_5_end">#fbc7d4</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_6_start">#e52d27</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_6_end">#b31217</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_7_start">#cc2b5e</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_7_end">#753a88</color>

<color name="color_bg_note_8_start">#00c6ff</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_8_end">#0072ff</color>

<color name="color_bg_note_9_start">#02AAB0</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_9_end">#00CDAC</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_10_start">#8360c3</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_10_end">#2ebf91</color>

<color name="color_bg_note_11_start">#12c2e9</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_11_center">#c471ed</color>
<color name="color_bg_note_11_end">#f64f59</color>
<color name="color_icon_popup_item">#706D6D</color>
<color name="color_bg_display_info_test">#242934</color>
<color name="color_ads">#FFCC66</color>
<color name="color_transparent">#00000000</color>
<color name="color_button_cancel">#f0f0f0</color>
<color name="color_button_ok">#0c84ff</color>
<color name="bnv_selected">#0283F3</color>
```

This is the themes.xml file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Base.Theme.Notepad" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/bg_main</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/bg_main</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/bg_main</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Notepad" parent="Base.Theme.Notepad" />
```

I already know how to adjust the light and dark themes. However, I am using most of the colors in colors.xml by customizing it (shape, selector..) in drawble. My problem now is that the theme can only adjust a few system properties and I don't know how to adjust that color file for each theme.

Comment: Sorry but what you exactly mean by "My problem now is that the theme can only adjust a few system properties"? Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 1):

create custom theme  and set on base screen

```
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
```

Comment: I already know how to do this, but it's not my problem

Answer (score 1):

Change the theme

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

Replace `AppTheme` with your desired theme

Change the color of a specific view

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

Replace `textView` with the ID of your view and `colorAccent` with the color resource you want to use

Comment: I already know how to do this, but it's not my problem. @Sundar Raj way is exactly what I wanted